# On Insert: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I tried creating my third table of phone numbers, I wrote the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE MYPHONE (EMPLOYEE_ID INT, PHONE_NUMBER INT)

INSERT INTO MYPHONE 
VALUES (1 , 7894561230)
```

But when I tried executing this previous `INSERT` command, I got an error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 46
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` probably isn't the best data type for a phone number - you don't need to do any arithmetic on phone numbers, so why use a numerical data type? Store it as a string (or `varchar` in SQL).

Also, if you **did** need to store a value as an `int`, 2,147,483,647 is the maximum - anything higher would "overflow", hence the error you're getting. A `long` (or `bigint` in SQL) would allow values up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

Answer (score 1):

Allowed range of `INT` datatype is **-2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647**

You can get more details on the allowed range [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You are trying to insert beyond that range. For phone number better choose `VARCHAR` data type. If you still want to go for number, in that case use `BIGINT` instead of `INT`.